# Sql to count total from 2 tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel, count

I have 2 table Bank and Applicant, how to query show all bank and count how much applicant that use that bank

**[Bank][1]**:

```
| id | Bank_desc    
|----|---------
| 1  | Ambank  
| 2  | Maybank  
| 3  | RHB BANK 
| 4  | OSBC
```

**[Applicant][2]**:

```
| id | Name | Bank|
|----|------|----|
|  1 | JACK |  3 |
|  2 | ANDY |  1 |
|  3 | VOID |  1 |
```

i want to show something like this,
**[Results][2]**:

```
| id | Bank     |Total|
|----|----------|----|
|  1 | Ambank   |  2 |
| 2  | Maybank  |  0 |
| 3  | RHB BANK |  1 |
| 4  | OSBC     |  0 |
```

i have try this sql

```
SELECT b.Bank_desc, Count(a.id),
FROM applicant a
LEFT JOIN bank b on b.id= a.bank
GROUP BY b.bank
```

but the result show only bank that have value

**[Results][2]**:

```
| id | Bank     |Total|
|----|----------|----|
|  1 | Ambank   |  2 |
| 2  | RHB BANK |  1 |
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why jquery ,php and laravel tag ?

Answer (score 1):

Your current query would work if you reversed the order of the tables:

```
SELECT
    b.id,
    b.Bank,
    COUNT(a.Bank) AS Total
FROM Bank b
LEFT JOIN Applicant a
    ON b.id = a.Bank
GROUP BY
    b.id,
    b.Bank;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: thanks tim, its works when i runnig on sql
the problem right now,convert sql to laravel code, i updated my laravel code on my question

Comment: @nvrzl No one is going to give you Laravel code in this question, because you asked for MySQL only.  If you need Laravel help, you'll have to open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT bank_name,
       Count(u.bank_id)
FROM   bank b
       LEFT JOIN users u
              ON b.id = u.bank_id
GROUP  BY u.bank_id
```